# Login forms: what's the benefit of asking for the email first?

Tags: authentication, login-control

I noticed that more and more websites are moving to a login form in 3 steps, as opposed to the more classic login+password form:

1. Asking for the email address
2. Verifying the email
3. Asking for the password

**What is the benefit of this login method, over the classic form?**

For instance, before/after on iCloud:

[image]

And Amazon:

[image]

If it is meant to improve security, I can't see how it is a benefit...

For instance, I entered a random email in iCloud's login form, and it prompted me for a password, although this email obviously didn't exist (it contained spaces and special characters).

For Amazon though, I got the following error:

> We cannot find an account with that email address

Which is a good way to verify that an email is registered on Amazon... and appears less secure to me, than a classic "the login/password combination is wrong".

Comment: Maybe the account is configured to use an authentication method that does not require a password. So would be impossible to ask for a password until that account has been checked to see if asking for a password is the correct next step. Or... maybe somebody flipped a coin to decide on 2 different UI proposals... who knows...

Comment: Or could it be used to prevent the browser from saving the login/password, and filling it automatically?

Comment: @piko: Could be anything... you will have to ask Apple and/or Amazon why they decided to do it... good luck

Answer (score 0):

IMO the benefit of using login form in 3 steps is to avoid [Phishing] For example- If you are requested to vote on some website and posting vote requires your Google credentials or any other. When you add your credentials then these credentials are posted to the server and you are redirected to the google page. This way user does not understand what has happened.

But with multiple step login Phishing can be avoided. When you are requested to vote (using Google credentials) then you will first insert your emailId then further it becomes mandatory to redirect you to google website for password and thus the credentials are not posted on to the anonymous server.

I hope you got it.

HTH Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For what I could read recently, the main reason is to avoid posting both username/email and password on a single request, making Man in The Middle attacks more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for the multi-step login is that logins are not always using an email and password combination, they can be using federated identity providers or some means of passwordless authentication.

Typically when you submit your email in the first step, a check is performed on the type of account and sign in procedure and then follow to the proper flow to complete the authentication.

As an example, for Apple iCloud:

When you submit the form with an email such as "user@example.org" which is not federated, a request is sent to an endpoint which replies with:

```json
{
  "showFederatedIdpConfirmation" : false,
  "federated" : false
}
```

After this the password prompt gets displayed to go with the default email and password login.

On the other hand, if you attempt to sign in with "user@apple.com", the response looks like:

```json
{
  "federatedIdpRequest" : {
    "idPUrl" : "https://idmsac.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/SAMLLogin?CertVersion=v2022A",
    "requestParams" : {
      "SAMLRequest" : "PD(...)Q+",
      "RelayState" : "ey(...)0=",
      "AccountName" : "user@apple.com"
    }
  },
  "federatedAuthIntro" : {
    "idpUrl" : "https://idmsac.apple.com",
    "idpName" : "https://idmsac.apple.com",
    "accountManagementUrl" : "https://appleconnect.apple.com",
    "orgType" : "enterprise",
    "orgName" : "Apple Inc."
  },
  "showFederatedIdpConfirmation" : true,
  "federated" : true
}
```

And displays a modal to complete the sign in for the Apple Inc. account at https://idmsac.apple.com.

In terms of security, as noted, it can be implemented in different ways. Apparently Apple took a better approach by not disclosing any information about missing account and fallback to the username/password combination, while Amazon took a not so secure approach, but not really related to the multi-step login.

Answer (score -2):

The reason that I could think was, even if you don't have your account with that provider, they might send some promotional messages saying you to signup.

By any chance you don't remember signing up for that website and try to login with a incorrect password they any way have to tell you to sign up first. But this is a cleaner way of doing things.

Asking your password makes things easier saying no need to verify the password and email both at the same time adding an extra layer of security to verify your account.

Comment: I would argue its "less secure" as hackers can now check for valid emails without even needing to try a password. Also, they could still add your email to a mailing list even if they asked for password on first page too, so your first point doesn't make sense... in my opinion